# Isomorphism of a Quotient Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

> Show that $(A \times B) \big/ (\mathfrak{a} \times \mathfrak{b}) \cong \big(A \big/ \mathfrak{a} \big) \times \big( B \big/ \mathfrak{b} \big)$.  Where $A$ and $B$ are commutative rings.

I am asked to prove this question but I am stuck.  Here are my thoughts:

Consider the map $f: A \times B \longrightarrow (A/\mathfrak{a}) \times (B/\mathfrak{b})$ given by $(x,y) \longrightarrow (\bar{x},\bar{y})$.

I believe that I should use the First Isomorphism Theorem for rings to show that the kernel of $f$ is  $\mathfrak{a} \times \mathfrak{b}$ which is an ideal of $A \times B$.  Also I believe I need to show that the map $f$ is a ring homomorphism.

Does any of this sound reasonable?  If so, where would I go from here?  If not, where should I begin?

Thank you for your help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is a good idea. Show that $f$ is a surjective homomorphism. Then note that $(x,y) \in \ker f$ iff $x \in \mathfrak{a}$ and $y \in \mathfrak{b}$ iff $(x,y) \in \mathfrak{a} \times \mathfrak{b}$.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  I am very grateful!